# Match only the decimal or integer value from string

Tags: regex

I want to get only the decimal or integer value from a string with regex.

The input string can have multiple possible formats.

I created some test cases for the expected output.

```
Input       Output
SEK49.09    49.09
SEK 49.09   49.09   
249,50.-    249,50
249.-       249
49-         49      
49.90       49.90   
399.90e     399.90  
49,90€      49,90   
525         525     
€28         28      
$29         29      
27,5 /h     27,5
27,5 text   27,5
```

Comment: `(\\d+(?:[\\.\\,]\\d+)?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but this pattern works for all of your test cases: `/[0-9]+([,.]?[0-9]+)*/g`

Comment: That would also match something like ",,,222" as a number, though.

Comment: I edited my answer with a more error-proof regex (let me know if I'm wrong!)

Comment: Looks better, though I think that would also match something like 5.5,5 since you've got the star on the end (I'm going from memory on a mobile here, so apologies if I'm wrong.)